# Using callbacks with Google Code Prettify

Tags: javascript

I am using [Google code prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) on a page (working correctly), and I want to add a function which is called once this process completes.

In the docs, they describe the following parameter:

```
callback=js_ident    window.exports["js_ident"] will be called when prettyprinting finishes. If specified multiple times, all are called.
```

However, I haven't been able to get this to work for me. I am obviously missing something about how the callback function is supposed to be defined/exported.

My header looks like this (when the page loads the code is prettified correctly but the alert does not show):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>function testing(){alert('hello')}}</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/prettify.js?callback=testing'></script>
```

Also, following [this example](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=226#c2), I have tried modifying the first block in a few different ways () a couple shown below), but with no change:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>window['exports'] = {testing: function(){alert('123')}}</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>window.exports = {testing: {apply: function(){alert('123')}}}</script>
```

How am I supposed to define my `testing` function so it can be called correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the `callback` parameter is only available on the `run_prettify.js` script, not the `prettify.js` script you're currently using.

Furthermore, [per the docs](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/wiki/GettingStarted), they want the function you specify in the `callback` parameter to be specified in the `window.exports` object.

E.g http://jsbin.com/atukuq/1/

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  window.exports = { 
    testing: function () {
      alert('hello');
    }
  }
</script>
<script src="https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/run_prettify.js?callback=testing"></script>
```

Comment: I completely missed that I was using `prettify.js` instead of `run_prettify.js`! That's exactly what I needed, thanks very much.

Comment: @Ben: No problem, sometimes a different pair of eyes is all you need ;)

Comment: By the way, is `window.exports` a standard or built-in object? I did not find much information on it while I was researching this question. The way they describe it in the docs made it seem like a standard practice to do it this way, is that the case?

Comment: The use of `exports` is common in script loading ([e.g. CommonJS](http://addyosmani.com/writing-modular-js/)); I would guess they stole the idea from there, but `window.exports` by itself is nothing.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
   window.exports = [];
   window.exports["testing"] = function() {
      alert("hello");
   }
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/run_prettify.js?callback=testing'></script>
```

Changes: run_prettify.js instead of prettify.js and defined function according to docs.